# sbt error: couldn't find or load main class ***********

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

I tried to run project from [this link](http://ics-software-engineering.github.io/play-example-login/). However, when I am running this project in sbt there is an **error :**

`Could not find or load main class *****`

This is how **my build.sbt** file looks like :

```
name := "play-example-login"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= seq(
javaJdbc,
javaEbean,
cache
)

play.Project.playJavasettings
```

I am newbie to java playframework, and unable to figure out what to change. I guess problem is in my sbt path variable. Thank-you in Advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I try to run project from your link. That ok.
You can run direct this project at cmd

```
activator run
```

[image]

This is good example !